dotnet test with variable string parameter
how can I use variable string parameter in dotnet test (Visual Studio 2022)
[Test]
public void MyTest(string MyString)
{
     Console.WriteLine(MyString);
}

and execute the test by command line with this variable string?
dotnet test "C:\MyPath\Test.dll" --filter "FullyQualifiedName=QualifyTest.ColorTest("This is my String")

Is it also possible to pass path names like "D:\This\is\my\path.txt" in the same way?
Should I use [TestCase] or [TestCaseSource] with included parameter instead and how?
I use NUnit 3.0
Thank you.

Finally I useed environment variables to do this task:
dotnet test "C:\MyPath\Test.dll" --filter "FullyQualifiedName=QualifyTest.ColorTest -e variable1="MyString" -e variable2="C:\a\path\to\file.txt"

and in code I use:
string var1 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("variable1");
string path1 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("variable2");

Ths works for me. Maybe there is a better solution.

I don't see direct way of doing it with some smart attribute, but you can always define static method that would return values TestContext.Parameters, which can be populated from settings file (usually known as .runsettings). Those run settings can be then sepcified in dotnet test command with --settings option pointing to file we want to use. The static method defined then can be used in TestCaseSource attribute to provide values.
Sample setup: add .runsettings1
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <TestRunParameters>
        <Parameter name="Foo" value="Bar" />
    </TestRunParameters>
</RunSettings>

and .runsettings2:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <TestRunParameters>
        <Parameter name="Foo" value="Something else" />
    </TestRunParameters>
</RunSettings>

Then, define unit tests:
public class Tests
{
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
    }

    [TestCaseSource(nameof(GetInputFromSettings))]
    public void NotNull(string s)
    {
        var myParam = TestContext.Parameters["Foo"];
        Assert.NotNull(myParam);
    }

    [TestCaseSource(nameof(GetInputFromSettings))]
    public void EqualToBar(string s)
    {
        var myParam = TestContext.Parameters["Foo"];
        Assert.AreEqual("Bar", myParam);
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> GetInputFromSettings()
    {
        yield return TestContext.Parameters["Foo"];
    }
}

Then you can perform these commands to see the results:
dotnet test -s .runsettings1 # passes 2 tests
dotnet test -s .runsettings2 # fails one test

UPDATE
Actually you can inherit TestCaseSourceAttribute and define there the method to provide values from run settings:
public class TestCaseSourceFromRunSettingsAttribute : TestCaseSourceAttribute
{
    public TestCaseSourceFromRunSettingsAttribute(string settingName) 
        : base(
            typeof(TestCaseSourceFromRunSettingsAttribute), 
            nameof(GetInputFromSettings), 
            [settingName])
    {
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> GetInputFromSettings(string settingName)
    {
        yield return TestContext.Parameters[settingName];
    }
}

References:

Tips and Tricks NUnit 3
Configure unit tests by using a .runsettings file

